# How do I restore default perl in macOS Mojave?

Tags: mojave, perl

Is there a way to restore default perl5 and cpan modules in Mojave without rebuilding the OS?

Comment: What happened to them?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I was concerned about trashing the OS default perl and cpan after a round of trying to use MacPorts's perl5. I could not get a Github perl project to build (make) with Macports, so I switched to the default perl and the make succeeded.  I was then afraid that the process might have mucked up default modules. Can you tell I am a perl noob? Anyway, after much perl -V and file diffs between a clean system and mine, I convinced myself it was fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard binaries are protected by SIP and can‘t easily be removed *nor* replaced. Booting into recovery and reinstalling macOS only is the easiest way to solve this. You may need to manually reinstall any user-installed CPAN modules again afterwards.

Comment: Thanks nohillside. I spaced out on SIP protections. I was concerned after reading many warnings about NOT using Apple's default perl for development. Anyway see my comment to @JBis also.